# Rails Custom ActionView::Template::Handler no data sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, renderer, actionview

I'm trying to create a template handler for CSV in rails 5.2.3

When I render anything through the template, all i get is "Network Error" for the file with no data sent

I can't seem to find ANYTHING on the net about how instance variables are passed from controller to template. if I use eval or instance_eval, I get errors for variables not found

```
require 'csv'
require 'action_view'

class CSVHandler
  VERSION = '0.5.2'

  class CSVGenerator
    def self.generate
      file = CSV.generate(encoding: 'UTF-8', force_quotes: true) do |csv|
        yield csv
      end
      file.html_safe
    end
  end

  class << self
    def default_format
      Mime[:csv]
    end

    def call(template)
      # how can I get the controller headers and response body here???

      <<-RUBY
        begin
          CSVHandler::CSVGenerator.generate do |csv|
            #{template.source}
          end
        end
      RUBY
    end

    def handles_encoding?
      true
    end

  ene
end

ActionView::Template.register_template_handler :csvrb, CSVHandler
```

sample template:

```
csv << [
  'Remit Number',
  'Positive Amount',
  'Negative Amount',
  'Successful Amount',
  'Failed Amount',
  'Net Amount',
  'Recorded?',
  'Reconciled?',
  'Locked?',
  'Link'
]
@remittance_list.each do |remittance|
  csv << [
    remittance.remit_number,
    remittance.positive_amount,
    remittance.negative_amount,
    remittance.successful_amount,
    remittance.failed_amount,
    remittance.net_amount,
    remittance.recorded,
    remittance.reconciled,
    remittance.locked,
    remit_form_url(remittance.remit_number),
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was setting the content-encoding to `deflate` (I'm used to streaming CSVs and I wanted to keep that functionality), after removing that, everything worked as expected

I ended up needing to create an entire gem for the functionality I was looking for (full streaming with templates). look at [csv_rb](https://github.com/SampsonCrowley/csv_rb) if you're interested

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23209537)

Comment: @Andreas I did include the essential part. i was including a `deflate` content-encoding header. removing it fixed the problem

Comment: the link is for a gem that is related, but not an answer to the problem. maybe read the answer before flagging it or commenting about links